# Does Dask support functions with multiple outputs in Custom Graphs?

Tags: python, dask

The [Custom Graphs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html#custom-graphs) API of [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org) seems to support only functions returning one output key/value.

For example, the following dependency could not be easily represented as a Dask graph:

```
    B -> D
   /      \
A-         -> F
   \      /
    C -> E
```

This can be worked around by storing a tuple under a "composite" key (e.g. "B_C" in this case) and then splitting it by `getitem()` or similar. However, that can lead to inefficient execution (e.g. unnecessary serialization) and reduce the clarity of DAG visualizations.

Is there a better way or is this currently not supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer

No, but it shouldn't matter.

#### Programming interface

You are correct that the correct way to manage multiple outputs with Dask is to use getitem.  In terms of programming interface, the standard way to do this with dask.delayed is with getitem as you suggest.  Here is an example:

```
from dask import delayed

@delayed(pure=True)
def minmax(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return a, b
    else:
        return b, a

result = minmax(1, 2)
min, max = result[0], result[1]
```

#### Performance

You raise an interesting question about performance.  In practice using the [distributed scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.org) (which works just fine on a single machine) should handle this sort of situation just fine without performance penalty.  The same would be true for the single-machine threaded scheduler.

Comment: works without the `pure` statement on dask-0.14.0, what is the purpose of `pure`? Can we use `nout` here?

Comment: Should work with or without pure.  Should work with nout.  Pure is used to avoid duplicate computations if given the same inputs.